# How low-contention transaction related to Aggregates in DDD?

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I am reading Evans DDD book. While analyzing cargo shipping system, he explains how to define Aggregates and their boundaries. And he explains us why he choose `HandlingEvent` as aggregate.

At first he explains:

> The **Handling Event** is another matter. Previously we have considered
>   two possible database queries that would search for these: one, to
>   find the **Handling Events** for a **Delivery History** as a possible
>   alternative to the collection, would be local within the **Cargo**
>   AGGREGATE; the other would be used to find all the operations to load
>   and prepare for a particular **Carrier Movement**. In the second case, it
>   seems that the activity of handling the Cargo has some meaning even
>   when considered apart from the Cargo itself. So the Handling Event
>   should be the root of its own AGGREGATE.

As I understood, he menas that *handling event* must be root of its own aggregate, we can get `Handling Events` based on `CareerMovements`. And there is no any relationship with `Cargo`.

Am I right here?

And then he shows that picture:

[image]

In that picture, I cant understand the relationship between low-contention and `HandlingEvent` Aggregate. What does author mean here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And there is no any relationship with Cargo

You may have overlooked one of the earlier modeling constraints; that handling events are uniquely identified by a tuple of completion time, event type, *and the Id of its Cargo*.
So given any handling event, you can use the cargo identifier to look up the appropriate cargo, and likewise given any cargo you can get a list of all matching handling events.

> I cant understand the relationship between low-contention and HandlingEvent Aggregate.

That is Not Your Fault[tm].  Evans, writing in 2003, is missing an important concept: [Domain Event](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html).  You'll find him discussing that idea in front of [DDD-NYC in 2009](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lE6Hxz4yomA).

It may also help you to orient yourself if you review the [dddsample](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core) implemented by DomainLanguage and Citerus.  In particular, look at the [handling infrastructure](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/infrastructure/messaging/jms/HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptConsumer.java).

In his example, handling events are messages coming from the real world (the ports where containers are loaded and unloaded, etc).  Each of those messages contain information about what happened, when, where, and to which `Cargo` -- the cargoId is part of the message.

So you could, in theory, load the cargo aggregate, add the handling event to it, perform any additional business logic, and so on.

But... adding the handling events to the cargo aggregate isn't entirely satisfactory, from a modeling perspective

> ... it seems that the activity of *handling* the Cargo has some meaning when considered apart from the Cargo itself.

The handling of the cargo is a record of activity in the real world, and *not* subject to the authority of the domain model.  The act of recording a handling event doesn't require any of the information enclosed within the cargo aggregate (because we have it from the event source), or any sort of oversight, so there's no justification for additional latency.

If you conclude that the handling event doesn't belong in the Cargo aggregate, what do you do with it?  Aggregate is the only hammer Evans has in 2003, so the event has to go into one, and with no convenient candidates at hand, he concludes that the event belongs to its own aggregate.

## Update

> as title of my question is about low-contention transaction, could you please give some notes regarding to this

"Low contention" is a design consequence of the process that he is trying to model.

> Entering a *Handling Event* is an operational activity that needs to be quick and simple, so an important application requirement is the ability to enter *Handling Events* *without contention*.

If you have contention -- two different processes trying to modify the same aggregate concurrently, then you need to be careful about locking to ensure that you neither lose data nor and up with your database in an internally inconsistent state.  Either processes have to block waiting to acquire the lock, or they have to repeat their calculations when the optimistic locking fails.

In a process where you need low latency, you need to eliminate unnecessary lock contention, and that means introducing smaller aggregates, each with their own individual locks.

If you didn't need low contention here, then you could more seriously consider a model where handling events are part of the Cargo aggregate.

Do Handling Events in the cargo shipping domain *really* need to be low latency?  I haven't the foggiest.  It might be that Evans needed an example to justify multiple aggregates, and invented this one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As your answer explains fully why to make `HandlingEvent` aggregate.
But, as title of my question is about `low-contention transaction`, could you please give some notes regarding to this apart from the video link?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You answer fully explains everything,